# How do I activate my virtual environment in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I'm using VSC and trying to activate my virtual environment through its terminal.

I've navigated to the project folder in terminal and ran:

`virtualenv ll_env` which seems to successfully create the virtual environment.

Now I tried to run `ll_env/bin/activate` and `ll_env\Scripts\activate.bat` to activate it but doesn't seem to do anything. Supposedly when I have activated it I'm supposed to see `(ll_env)learning_log` in terminal. Please help. I've attached a screenshot as well.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: no ... dont do python3... just `./11_env/bin/activate` (or maybe activate.cmd on win)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
.\ll_env\Scripts\activate
```

Comment: I'm getting the error  ```File C:\Users\moehe\Desktop\CS\learning_log\ll_env\Scripts\activate.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system...```

Comment: I just ran it in cmd, it worked. But, can I continue using VSC after I do that in command prompt?

Comment: I also faced the same error when I used windows , but I could not figure a solution so I kept running it in cmd

Comment: I got it thanks. Curious to know if anyone knows the fix in VSC.

Comment: also just try `python .\ll_env\Scripts\activate_this.py`

Comment: It didn't work. A window came up for a split second then closed.

Answer (score 0):

Select `Activate.ps1` and right-click to choose `copy path`, then paste it to terminal, press `Enter` to activate virtual environment:

[image]

And, with the default setting if you never change it:

```
"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true
```

pressing `Ctrl+Shift+ to open a new terminal will activate the virtual environment automatically.

Answer (score 0):

try this. I'm using Windows too. And working for me

```
cd Scripts
activate
```