# How can I debug Python console_script command line apps with the VSCode debugger?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I've a Python package `package_name` which provides a command line application `command-line-app-name` as `console_script`:

`setup.py`:

```
setup(
    ...
    entry_points={"console_scripts": ["command-line-app-name=package_name.cli:main"]},
    ...
)
```

The virtualenv is located in `<project>/.venv` and managed with `pipenv`. `pipenv` managed venvs should support VSCode debugging integration. I've created a debugger configuration `launch.json` file with setting the Python path to the venv (`pythonPath`):

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: command-line-app-name",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "program": "command-line-app-name",
            "linux": {
                "pythonPath": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/bin/python",
                "args": ["-r", "/home/florian/gitlab/package_name/data/Test_MRM.d"]
            },
            "windows": {
                "pythonPath": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/Scripts/python.exe",
                "args": ["-r", "D:\\MassHunter\\Data\\demo_0000.d"],
            },
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

The Windows and Linux specific venv python executable and command line arguments should not have an impact. If I run the debugger I get: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/florian/gitlab/package-name/command-line-app-name'`. It seems like I'm miss-interpreting the documentation somehow. I tried to find help w.r.t. [vscode-python](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python) as well as [debugpy](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy) without success. How can I debug a console script command line app (instead of a package module)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`console_scripts` cannot be debugged out-of-the-box. The solution is to call the entry point function directly instead (`"program": "${workspaceRoot}/package_name/cli.py",`). This requires to add the `if __name__ == '__main__':` idiom in the corresponding module (here: `cli.py`). In my case the command line argument parser used is `click`. However the pseudo-code should be very similar for other command line parser libs.

`package_name/cli.py`:

```
@click.command()
@click.option(...)
def main(<args>, <kwargs>):
    ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()  # pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter
```

`.vscode/launch.json`:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: command-line-app-name",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/package_name/cli.py",
            "linux": {
                "pythonPath": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/bin/python",
                "args": ["-r", "/home/florian/gitlab/package_name/data/Test_MRM.d"]
            },
            "windows": {
                "pythonPath": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/Scripts/python.exe",
                "args": ["-r", "D:\\MassHunter\\Data\\demo_0000.d"],
            },
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

**NOTE**: The tool used to manage the venv makes a difference. This solution does work in case the venv is managed with `pipenv`. The solution does not work in case the venv is managed with `poetry`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `launch.json` that worked for me to debug mkdocs plugins:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "module": "mkdocs",
            "args": ["serve"]
        }
    ]
}
```

mkdocs provides the `mkdocs` entry point that accepts several arguments such as `build` and `serve`. This `launch.json` allowed me to set a breakpoint in a mkdocs plugin python file and stop at that breakpoing after running the mkdocs build/serve process.

Comment: Running as a module, i.e. `python -m mkdocs ...`, is not the same thing as running a console script, which would just look like `mkdocs ...`.