How to debug a Python CLI package in Visual Studio Code?
I'm developing a Python project that runs in the CLI using the following command:
my-python-package --config config.yaml

Recently, some dependencies were updated, leading to deprecated or eliminated functions that I need to debug.
I’m using Visual Studio Code (VS Code) and have attempted to create a launch.json configuration, but it only works when running a specific Python file directly. My project does not have a main.py, and executing the entry point does not produce any results.
My goal is to run the CLI command and debug it visually in VS Code, similar to how one would debug a regular Python file.
I have tried various configurations in launch.json, as suggested in How to debug a Python module in Visual Studio Code's launch.json, but none have worked since my project is not structured as a traditional module. I also asked ChatGPT for help, but it continues to suggest executing the entry point, which does not work either.
Project tree
my-project-folder
├── __init__.py
├── callbacks
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── core.py
│   └── notifiers.py
├── config
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── models.py
├── exceptions.py
├── experiments.py
├── mlflow.py
├── optuna
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── types.py
├── scripts
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── run_experiment.py <- This is the entry point in setup.py
└── utils.py
example.py

Output
Trying with the following launch.json
{
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
       {
           "name": "Debug python project CLI",
           "type": "debugpy",
           "request": "launch",
           "module": "project_name_folder",
           "console": "integratedTerminal",
           "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
           "env": {},
           "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
           "justMyCode": true
       }
   ]
}

Executing code

Give the following error:
> cd .../projectName ; /usr/bin/env ../projectName/.venv/bin/python .../.vscode/extensions/ms-python.debugpy-2024.10.0-linux-x64/bundled/libs/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher 55561 -- -m project_name_folder

.../ProjectName/.venv/bin/python: No module named ProjectName.__main__; 'project-name' is a package and cannot be directly executed

Development process:

I installed the package locally for the first time using the following commands:
python -m venv .venv && source .venv/bin/activate && pip install -e .


Then I modify the code in VSC and run the CLI trying to fix the errors.


Current launch.json configuration:
Here's my current launch.json, which works for a specific example file:
{
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
       {
        "name": "Python Debugger: train_svm.py file",
        "type": "debugpy",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "example.py",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "args": [
           "examples/experiments/config.yaml"
        ],
        "justMyCode": true
     }
   ]
}

However, when I try to run the CLI command, I encounter different errors.
EDIT
I posted my solution in How can I debug Python console_script command line apps with the VSCode debugger?

You may check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64556874/how-can-i-debug-python-console-script-command-line-apps-with-the-vscode-debugger .

Adding the idiomatic if name == 'main': app() to the entry point file worked. However, I still get the same errors as when I run the Python file directly. Meanwhile, using the CLI command results in different errors. Thanks for your comment, that was useful anyways.

@AmadeuszLiu Should I mark this question as duplicated and post my solution in your suggested stackoverflow post?
